# Do devices with different screen densities really look that different?

Tags: android

I only have one actual device to test on, a Nexus One but I've briefly used a Droid X in the past. I recall a better looking screen but I don't remember it fitting more icons on the home screen than my N1. So I'm wondering if my emulators and such are truthful or not.

I'm running 2 emulators, WVG800, one at 240 the other 160. The 240 looks right. The 160 doesn't, everything is much smaller including buttons, radio buttons, things that I have not specified an exact size for. The [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document shows different densities looking exactly the same in the image below. However, my emulators do not maintain that look. Is something wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have different display size in real world. WVGA800 with density 240 is likely to be a phone with 4" screen. And WVGA800 with density 160 is probably a tablet with 7" screen. Check the option `Scale display to real size` when you starting emulator to see the difference.

Comment: Makes sense. I don't see that option to scale display to real size though.

Comment: When I run the app, the emulator just starts, I don't have any launch options dialog.

Comment: Do you run emulator from Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I do run it from Eclipse.

Comment: Open Android Virtual Device Manager. Select desired emulator and click "Start..." button. It is showing me lauch options.

Comment: there it is, I've been launching from the green play button. thanks